# Should I check for return value of collaborators in unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

Suppose I following classes:

```
class A {
 private B b;
 private int milkQuantity;

 A(B b) {
  this.b = b;
 }

 public getCoffee() {
  milkQuantity = b.getMilk(1);

  return secretRecipe();    
 }

 ...
}
```

So, while unit testing should I mock class `B` and check if `getMilk()` method was called or I should check if it returns the correct milk quantity(i.e 1 cup)? for the latter case I need to setup class `B`  in my unit test.

According to me we need to check the behavior of class `B` in its own unit test, class `A` should be concerned only if the correct method was called or not.

**Update 1**

Making my point more clear:

on calling `a.getCoffee()` should I test:

```
assertThat(a.milkQuantity).isEqualTo(1);
```

**OR**

```
verify(b).getMilk();
```

Comment: If you are testing `A`, you only need to check that `A` is doing what it is supposed to. If you are testing `B`, you need to check that `B` is doing what it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing **unit** tests, you need to handle each unit (usually - a class) in its own test. SO `B` needs its own test and `A` needs a test with a mocked instance of `B` to test its using it correctly. You don't need to check `getMilk`'s return value (after all - you're mocking it), but you do need to check that `B` is using it correctly - i.e. that `secretRecipe` is being called with the same value `getMilk` returned.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you would want to test the behavior of `getCoffee` and not how it's implemented. Perhaps in the future you will implement it differently but with the same behavior and that shouldn't break your unit test. So I would recommend just testing the result of `getCoffee`. It's fine to mock `b.getMilk`.

When testing I would recommend doing something like

```
B b = new B() {
    @Override
    public int getMilk(int x){
        // Mock implementation
    }
}

A a = new A(b);
Coffee expected = ... // Manually construct a Coffee object with expected values
assertEquals(expected, a.getCoffee())
```